# DocuSign C# API (Create Tabs)

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to update the tabs while using an embedded sending API.

```
SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
signHere.AnchorString = "Approved by  :";
signHere.AnchorXOffset = "0";
signHere.AnchorYOffset = "-50";

signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(signHere);
envelopesApi.CreateTabs(accountId, envelopeId, "1", signer.Tabs);
```

The code runs perfectly fine with no errors but the tabs does not appear in the embedded sending interface. How should I go about resolving it?

Comment: Also, this tab appears when I make an API call to list the tabs as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I found out that the problem with the above was not with the tagging.

In the same method as above, I did an update of the document:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
doc.Name = docName;
doc.FileExtension = docExtension;
doc.DocumentId = "1";

EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();
envDef.Documents.Add(doc);

envelopesApi.UpdateDocuments(accountId, envelopeId, envDef);
```

I believe the tagging mentioned in the question was then tagged onto the original document instead of the updated document.

To fix this, delete the document before updating it as such:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
doc.Name = docName;
doc.FileExtension = docExtension;
doc.DocumentId = "1";

EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envDef.Documents = new List<Document>();
envDef.Documents.Add(doc);

envelopesApi.DeleteDocuments(accountId, envelopeId, envDef);
envelopesApi.UpdateDocuments(accountId, envelopeId, envDef);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the anchor string is not matching. I suggest a simple anchor string without spaces or special characters.

Eg, try with

```
signHere.AnchorString = "Approved";
```

A better solution if you have access to the source document is to add a tiny DSL to the doc such as `approval_signer`

Put that string where you want the Signer Tab to appear. Mark the text color of the string to be white so it won't be visible.

Comment: Found out the reason. I updated the document as well in an earlier part of the code. Thanks!

Comment: @ButterBeer Cool can you accept Larry's answer in that case (or add a new one explaining how you solved) for the benefit of the community?  Thx

Comment: Will do.. I'll explained the problem in a new answer, it was as I did both updates to the document as well as updates to the tagging which led to the tags not being shown.